# jQuery script for finding elements by typing and organize them

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I would like to search by any term (name, user, from, price), and display the div into top and hide the ones who doesn't have the typed value.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sc9ys/10/

I would like to have the same result as the `jquery mobile table filter` http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/filterable/

Where you can search for any term.

I know that for search for any term I should use `$(list).find("li *:)...` but I can't figure out how to display the items properly. If you test my jsfiddle it doesn't work very well.

**Edit**: As asked by the user below, here's some more info.

```
<ul id='list'>
   <li>
       <div class='row'>
           <div class='middle'>
               <ul>
                    <li><h3>Stackoverflow</h3></li>
                    <li><span>User</span></li>
                    <li><span>London</span></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
           <div style='clear: both'></div>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>

$("#search").change( function () {
     $(list).find("li *:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: You should post some of your relevant code as well as supplying a fiddle. For the reason that the code stays with the question and future users can reference it even when fiddle is no more.

Comment: `<div class='middle' />` in your fiddle contains invalid html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved guys. Thank you all.

You can see the following example working at: http://jsfiddle.net/Sc9ys/29/

```
$('#search').on('keyup change', function(){
     var str = $.trim($(this).val());
     if (str) {
        search(str, $("#list"));
     } else {
        $("#list").find('li').show();
        /* The <li> are display: none, to show them again if the input type is clear, 
         we must find those <li> and show them. Showing only the #list isn't enough. */
     }
});

function search(toFind, list){
    $(list).find('li').filter(function() {

       $li = $(this);

       $li.find(".middle :contains(" + toFind +")").parent().parent().slideDown();

       $li.find(".middle").not(":contains(" + toFind + ")").parent().parent().slideUp();

    });                        
}

/* Function to search with the input lowercase */
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

*Edit*: Made some adjustments according to the help of user @Joraid.

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8XMBX/)

The idea is in

```
 $("#ul_container").find("li").filter(function () {//your comparing logic here });
```

Here, try this out. Honesty I couldn't read thru your code, so I made this example. I added the sub items (spans that contain data to be searched) in an array `datalist` by their class name.

**Generic Search Function.**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="search" />

<ul id="ul_container">
    <li class="listItem">
        <span class="car">Honda</span>
        <span class="country">Japan</span>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
        <span class="car">BMW</span>
        <span class="country">Germany</span>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

**Script:**

```
  //Capture user input
 $("#search").on("keyup change", function () {
    var str = $.trim($(this).val());
    if (str) {
        search(str);
    } else {
        // if no input, then show all
        $(".listItem").show();
    }
});


//the search part. 
 var datalist = ["car", "country"];
function search(toFind) {
         //select all li and loop thru them one by one
        $("#ul_container").find("li").filter(function () {
           var $li = $(this);//hold current li in a variable
             //loop thru all sub spans by their class and check if the toFind keyword is there
            // you modify this step, i use it to specify which sub span to be searched. Sometimes I don't want all field to be searched, only the ones I select. 
            for (var i = 0; i < datalist.length; i++) {
                    //hold the span in a var called $item
                var $item = $li.children("." + datalist[i]);
                var content_str = $item.html();//get the actual string
                //the comparing code
                if (content_str.toLowerCase().indexOf(toFind.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                    $li.show();
                    break;
                } else {
                    $li.hide();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I've been trying to adapt your code to my needs and I've come to this: http://jsfiddle.net/Sc9ys/15/, it's not working very well. It hides "stackoverflow" I don't know why.

Comment: You need to clean your html, parent() and child() function will not work correctly because you nested element inside each other <li> inside <span>. Plus, you need to give a clear id/class names so JQuery can easily access them.

Comment: If you give the <li> or <span> that you want to search a class, it can be easily found by finding the parent li then .find("SITE_NAME") for example.

Comment: look at this update jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sc9ys/16/. I'm getting somewhere. Now I only have three problems: when searching it should show all the elevents inside that div (it only shows what you search); It should hide the other divs; when I clear the input type it should show again all the elements.

Comment: It won't work, let's say I found the a row <ul> how can I reach the inner content? I reach to the row (parent li)that contains a child element with the content "Microsoft", but I cannot find that element because there is no pattern. One time you r putting <h3> inside <li> etc etc. Try to give a class to all inner element that you want it to be searched. Check my example html.

Comment: I've reached the elements inside the `li` and also I've hide the `<li>` that doesn't have the value typed. Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sc9ys/20/

My problem now: why d'hell does the content is hidden and `.middle` class and `.row` class is `display: none`? Can you help me with that?

Comment: Edit: I only need to show the list again when the input type is clear. http://jsfiddle.net/Sc9ys/24/

Comment: Also solved the question above. Now I only need to set the search for `toLowerCase()`

Comment: Ok good to hear that,since you used $li.find(".middle") which will target your search into the .middle class. From what I see the search works on both lower and upper case.

Comment: But I noticed one issue, let's say you type lon or lond or london, first row only will appear, let's say you type Long by mistake, then corrected it by hitting backspace so it become lon, then the first row should appear. But now it doesn't.

Comment: What is your suggestion?

Comment: The code slides up when the text is not found, but only get shown if the #search input is empty! therefore every time the user type into the search, check if found, then show, otherwise, slideup. 

In other words, just reverse the operation of you slideUp line. Here -> ($li.find(".middle:contains(" + toFind +")").parent().parent().show();
)

Comment: Ok, good point. Working fine. Already edited my answer to this post.